# Emacs AUCTeX highlighting setup

Tags: emacs, latex, highlighting, auctex

I'm using Emacs 24.2 under windows (7) together with AUCTeX and I'm experience problems with the syntax highlighting setup. From Linux I'm used to things like:

```
\documentclass[color]{../sty/tudbook}<br/>
```

highlighting nicely.

But in my windows configuration only `\section`, `\textbf` and the likes highlight properly, but things like `\cite` `\usepackage` `\begin{itemize}` etc. does not. I have tried looking into font-latex but here I only find the setup for the things that I see already working.

Where do I do the setup for and/or enable the other highlighting?

Comment: The underlying OS should have no influence, so I recommend you compare the two Emacs configs you're using.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I'm an idiot :)
Apparently I used (custom-set-faces ... ) in my .emacs under Windows. This seem to destroy the standard highlighting.